# GCP Cloud Functions with spring cloud function and spring native

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-functions, spring-cloud-function, spring-native

I have been trying to deploy a GCP cloud function using Spring Cloud Function and Spring Native unfortunately it seems that GCP is blocking the AOT mode as shown in the photo "AOT mode disabled"

[image]

Does anyone had success deploying a native spring cloud function ?

Jonathan.

Comment: AOT is not supported by Cloud Functions. Use Cloud Run intead, compile natively your code and deploy your container.

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere,

AOT isn’t supported by Cloud Functions,  you can use Cloud Run instead, to compile and deploy your container.

You can also try referring to this [codelabs quickstart](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/spring-native-quickstart#0) to get you started with the Spring Native on Google Cloud.